# HTTPD Centos 7 Bad Request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, httpd.conf

Well, I have a bizzard problem and this is the first time, 
**OS: Centos 7** 
**Apache:**

```
Server version: Apache / 2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built: Aug 5 2020 16:41:29
```

My problem is as follows:
I have no redirection in the httpd.cnf configuration file, nor in the hosts files, .htaccess cannot redirect to https.

all http requests returned error:

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "- // IETF // DTD HTML 2.0 // EN">
<html> <head>
<title> 400 Bad Request </title>
</head> <body>
<h1> Bad Request </h1>
<p> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. <br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port. <br />
  Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please. <br />
</p>
</body> </html>
```

I created the unsafe.cnf file in the conf.d folder by putting this line: `HTTPProtocolOptions unsafe`.
in my hosts, i have tested two solution :  
1 - redirect to https :

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1008" "#1008"
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example.com:443>
SuexecUserGroup "#1008" "#1008"
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /directory/html
SSLEngine On
...
</VirtualHost>
```

2- Other Solution :

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1008" "#1008"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /directory/html
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example.com:443>
SuexecUserGroup "#1008" "#1008"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /directory/html
SSLEngine On
...
</VirtualHost>
```

3- Solution : 
in .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So with this configuration or without like that's the server work fine with https and http return bad request.

With CURL :

```
# curl -sD  - http://jelocalise.maroccrm.com

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2020 13:32:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.6.40
Content-Length: 362
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
 Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

N.B : Sorry for my bad English

Comment: share error log in question.

Answer (score 1):

> Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.

You somehow have configured HTTPS on port 80, which is usually used for plain HTTP. That's why the following succeeds:

```
$ curl -k  https://jelocalise.maroccrm.com:80
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="Dolibarr Development Team">
....
```

Likely somewhere in your config (you only show a part) there is SSLEngine configured globally for port 80 or for some VirtualHost.

Comment: You are rigth thanks , one of my VirtualHost has declaration like this : <VirtualHost exemple.com:80 exemple.com:443> and inside  SSLEngine On, so I duplicated the configuration and remove SSLEngine inside :80 and now working thanks.